# Meaning of まだまだ in fighting manga context

Tags: meaning, manga, japanese-to-english

1 character said this after she has beaten 2 opponents on battle

**まだまだ**なのだっ！
俺にやっつけられたいヤツは、かかってくるのだ！

I feel like the meaning of "madamada" here is not "I'm not tired yet"/"You're still have a long way to go before you can beat me"

If anyone can please help me confirm the meaning if my understanding was wrong

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The meaning of "madamada" in this context is "I'm not tired yet" or "I can still keep (fighting)".

If the following text is not "俺にやっつけられたいヤツは、かかってくるのだ！" but something like "出直してこい(come back again)", "madamada" will mean "You're still have a long way to go before you can beat me", but in this case, from this following text " 俺にやっつけられたいヤツは、かかってくるのだ！", he wants to keep fighting, so that "I'm not tired yet" or "I can still keep (fighting)" is much more suitable.